# Where do I link the python path for BVLC caffe windows python implementation

Tags: python, windows, neural-network, caffe

I successfully built a windows port of caffe (https://github.com/BVLC/caffe) and I need to be able to import its python implementation into other scripts in python, such as `import caffe`.

I know how to update environment variables using the windows GUI, but what path do I update to?

Some possible options I can think of: `C:/Project/caffe/` `C:/Project/caffe/build/` `C:/Project/caffe/build/python/` `C:/Project/caffe/build/python/[???]/` `C:/Project/caffe/python/`

Let me know if there is missing information here, or if I'm missing something.

Comment: Have you come to a solution?